# Fill an Input without selecting it before. HTML / JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to fill an input without having to select it with my mouse before. Just using javascript and not Jquery .

What I mean is that they user just have ton type his answer and it goes directly into the input. Here is my HTML.

```
<input id="inputresponse" name="response" type="text" value="" />
```

I have searched everywhere but I can't find a clue. I guess we should use either keyup or keypress, but I can't find how.

Your help is highly appreciated, thanks !

Comment: add `autofocus` to the input

Comment: Still doesn't focus on my input automatically when I type on my keyboard :/

Comment: Answer found below.
Thanks :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#inputresponse').focus();
```

Just setting this on your page will automatically focus on the input element and anything typed will be added within.

Comment: Perfect, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

> Use Autofocus on HTML tag as -

```html
<input id="inputresponse" name="response" type="text" autofocus>
```

> Another Way, You can use js also -

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById("inputresponse").focus();
}
```

```html
<input id="inputresponse" name="response" type="text">
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, but the focus directly in the JS does. Thanks mates :) :

Comment: Does with JS though, thanks !